# How to get google analytics cookie when you are programming a webscraper app?

Tags: http, flutter, cookies, dart, request

I want to make a nice webscraper app in flutter, but I face some problems. I use the simple dart http library to send requests.

Only problem is, i need to get the _ga and _gid cookies for some of my requests. How can i get these cookies in code?

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart';
//cookie is a String
void _tryLogin(String email,String password, BuildContext context) async{
  response = await post(
    'https://www.theUrlNeeded.funnyland',
    body:{
      "user" : email,
      "pass" : password,
    }
  );
  cookie = response.headers["set-cookie"];
```

It really works jut fine, i get back a PHPSession cookie and later on i just pass that cookie in my requests and i can access what i want. The problem is, when i want to checkout, i need _ga and _gid (google analytics) cookies to access the cart. (I really dont know why). As I learned after 3 days these cookies are created by an external javascript file. (https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js). How can i get these cookies?

I'm sure i need this, because i copied those cookies from my browser, pasted into my code and so i could reach my cart with the items i added on browser.

The most funny thing is I already created the same thing in python but it is an ugly command-line tool. But for some reasons it works perfectly even though i dont mess there with cookies.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your code? It would help to answer your question.

Comment: @GiulioMicheloni added code

Comment: Something is really bullcrap here, i checked my python code. There i work with htmlsession from the library requests and requests_html. It just keeps the same phpsession cookie, but somehow still manages to get the results correctly.